# simulate web interaction with python php session_start() doesn't work

Tags: php, python-3.x, session, cookies

I have the following html page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo '<!-- cookies  -->';
foreach($_COOKIE as $k => $v) {
    echo '<!-- ' . $k . '=>' . $v . ' -->';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

which yields the following page source when I view the page with https://daley.ws/file1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- cookies  --><!-- PHPSESSID=>22u20jsi288vtk5epser56d2bn7leb6n --></body>
</html>
```

the following python code is run on my mac:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

import urllib.request

REQ_HOST = "daley.ws"
DALEY_WS = 'https://daley.ws'
DALEY_WS_FILE1 = '{}/file1.php'.format(DALEY_WS)
DALEY_WS_FILE2 = '{}/file2.php'.format(DALEY_WS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(DALEY_WS_FILE1)
    req = urllib.request.Request(DALEY_WS_FILE1,\
            unverifiable=True, origin_req_host=REQ_HOST,\
            method='POST')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        data = response.read().decode()
    print('data: {}'.format(data))
```

and produces the following output:

```
https://daley.ws/file1.php
data: <html>
<body>
<!-- cookies  --></body>
</html>
```

why is the PHPSESSID cookie not present? and how do I fix the python code so that the page produces the proper output.

Comment: You dump the content of `$_COOKIE`  - where do you set any cookies in your Python code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the Python code.

When you load the page the first time in the browser, the cookie is not in the source code. But when you refresh it (the second request, but with `Cookie:`) it is in the source code.

It's not present in HTML, because the PHP session cookie is NOT in `$_COOKIE`, unless you send the cookie in the first place with HTTP header `Cookie:`. Try `session_id()` in PHP or `response.getheader("Set-Cookie")` in Python to get the current session cookie.

Comment: From what I can tell, the session_start() on the first line of the HTML/PHP sets the PHPSESSID cookie, doesn't it? It seems to when used in the web browser, but not in the Python code.

Comment: It actually does set it. `session_start()` returns a cookie called `PHPSESSION`, but it's up to the Python code to pick that up.

Comment: I believe the problem here is that the the python client is unverifiable. Right?

Comment: Other irregularities with python are causing me to switch back to Java.